# Is the $K$-Theory of $\mathbb{P}X$ a $\lambda$-Ring?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

If we let $\mathbb{P}X$ denote the free commutative algebra generated by the spectrum $X$, then we have a weak equivalence 
$$
\mathbb{P}X\simeq \bigvee_r E\Sigma_{r+}\wedge_{\Sigma_r}X^{\wedge r}.
$$
My question is whether $K(\mathbb{P}X)$ is known to be a $\lambda$-ring.  If so, is there a reference?  Thanks.